# How to use singleton class for get and Post the json values in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I developing a xamarin application using singleton based to get the server values. Searched the example by StackOverflow in this site([Show List in Xamarin consuming REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049857/show-list-in-xamarin-consuming-rest-api?rq=1)). but I have small doubts about this.  no one reply to my comment to this question.

My Code:

```
public async Task<Response> GetList<T>(string urlBase, string servicePrefix, string controller)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();          
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlBase);
            var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", servicePrefix, controller);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return new Response
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = result,
                };
            }

            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(result);

            return new Response
            {
                IsSuccess = true,
                Message = "Ok",
                Result = list,
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Response
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                Message = ex.Message,
            };
        }
    }
```

My doubt what is Response in this code. It is a separate class or HTTP response message. but I changed the HTTP response message, it gives an error in the above-declared variables(Success, Message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response` is a Custom class like following code,.It contails three properties.

```
    public class Response
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public object Result { get; set; }
    }
```